# Why the CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification doesn't hava any callback?

Tags: objective-c

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(addressBookDidChange:) name:CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification object:nil];

-(void)addressBookDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification{
    NSLog(@"change!!!");
}
```

I register ***CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification*** to the ***NSNotificationCenter***,but when app become bg, the contact has some change(e.g Add a new contact), and than app become activce, the register method doesn't have any callback(No log "change").

P.S

But when i add method

```
ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(ABAddressBookCreate(), addressBookChandedCallback, nil);


static void addressBookChandedCallback(ABAddressBookRef ab, 
CFDictionaryRef info, void *context){`

NSLog(@"address change!!!");

}
```

**Log:**

address change!!!

change!!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your code, not framework. The code if you put it in view controller should look like this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(addressBookDidChange:) name:CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)addressBookDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    //Handle event here...
    NSLog(@"change!!!");

}
```